# Managing bytes in X86 64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm currently working on a compiler that will translate source code to assembly and then using `nasm` to actually assemble the code. My goal in this language is to have integer declaration like C style languages where I would have `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, and `int64` as those map to `db`, `dd`, `dw`, and `dq` in assembly. I've already tinkered with doing something like:

```
num_1 db 300
```

where I see there is an overflow warning that displays but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the following:

```
section .text
    global _start
section .int_8 write
    int_8 db 5
section .text
    _start:
        mov al, [int_8]
        push 300
        pop rbx
        add rax, rbx
```

If I run the code via `gdb` and have a look at what's going on, I can see that after the `add` call, the `info registers rax` displays `305` as I would expect. If I run `info registers al` to access only the first 8 bits, I see `49`. Am I correct in assuming that I'm seeing `49` because the value has wrapped (305 - 256 = 49)? And if this is correct, is there a way, in assembly, to raise a buffer overflow to keep the code "safe"? Meaning if I go over the maximum size of `256` a buffer overflow warning is raised instead of just wrapping the value?

**Addendum**

Thanks to everyone in the comments I have some simple overflow check code for 8-bit integer addition that looks like:

```
 pop rcx ;; Get return address
 pop rax
 movzx rbx, al ;; Move 8 bits into the rbx registery
 cmp rax, rbx
 je no_overflow_int_8
 jne has_overflow_int_8
 no_overflow_int_8:
 push rcx
 ret
 has_overflow_int_8:
 mov rax, 60
 mov rdi, 8
 syscall
```

that will error with some arbitrary exit code. However, when I went to check 32-bit overflow. I found that if I loaded a value like `4294967290` that was declared as a `dd` into `rax`, and then I looked at the value using `info registers eax`, I saw a negative number. So the check turned into determining if `eax` after the add was greater than 0 which doesn't seem right as a check given if I use `100` the value in `eax` is actually 100. I'm a bit confused as to why `rax` shows the number correctly but `eax` is a negative number. I would assume I could put `2^32` as the maximum integer value into `eax` but maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, you are more or less correct — it is not that the value has wrapped, but if you observe the bit pattern of only the low 8 bits that's the number that you get.  In one sense, the value 305 overflows 8 bit storage, so in 8 bits, the value truncates.  Truncation to 8 bits is like modulus with 256 (rather than subtracting 256).  305 % 256 = 49.  Since 305 != 49, this represents overflow.

Comment: Buffer overflow is pointer or array index out of bounds and generally separate from 8-bit overflow.  Most of us will do indexing in larger data size, like 32- or 64-bit.  The issue with buffer overflow is using a fixed size array with lack of proper bounds checking and input/usage that is larger than the fixed size of the array.

Comment: There is no buffer here (so no buffer overflow), arguably there's integer overflow, are you interested in detecting those? It would be simpler if the "size" of the add instruction was the actual size that you intended (8-bit add for 8-bit additions and so on)

Comment: Each of buffer overflow, arithmetic overflow (your example), and truncation overflow can be detected.  Buffer overflow requires bounds checking, so basically knowing the size of the array and comparing an index to the maximum logical index for the array.  Arithmetic overflow can be detected using the processor flags after arithmetic (there's also other approaches).  Truncation overflow can be detected by the seeing if the original value and the truncated value are same or different.

Comment: So the check would go something like a `cmp rax, al` and if they are not equal jump to wherever I can raise an error and exit appropriately? Or does it need to be a bit more verbose where I take the value in `rax` after the `add`, do a `mod` call, and then compare and raise an error?

Comment: Yes, that `cmp` and the rest of the approach would work, but only theoretically.  The problem is that processor doesn't support that particular comparison, it wants to work on two operands of the same size.  One reason, among many others, it doesn't support that particular `cmp` is that you would also have to tell it whether to treat `al` as unsigned or signed.  So, instead what is done is to programmatically expand `al` from 8 bits to 64 bits by choosing either zero extension (as if unsigned) or sign extension (as if signed), so that the comparison can be done in 64 bits.

Comment: E.g. `movzx rbx, al` or `movsx rbx, al` — here using another register so as to not destroy the original.  Now you can do `cmp rax, rbx` and the rest of the branching sequence, where equal means no truncation and not equal means truncation overflow.

Comment: As others have said, another approach for x86 might be to do the addition in 8 bits and detect overflow afterward using the flags.  This would work for smaller numbers, (like, say, 100+5=105) but 8-bit addition is not appropriate for one operand here, 300, as 300 is already out side of the 8-bit range,  Logically speaking, to do that you would have 300 in a larger size than 8-bit and get truncation overflow converting 300 to 44 in 8-bit before even doing the 8-bit addition (which would "work" in the sense of not indicating error, if the truncation overflow were undetected) as in  44+5=49.

Comment: `cmp rax, al` can't work, its operands aren't the same size.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp).  To check for non-zero bits in RAX outside AL, do `cmp rax, 256` / `jae unsigned_overflow`.  Or `test rax, 0xffffffffffffff00` / `jnz` to directly test bits.  To check if RAX is the sign-extension of AL, yes as @ErikEidt says you'd want to sign-extend into a temporary register like `movsx rcx, al` and compare those 64-bit regs.

Comment: If you want to detect 8-bit overflow when it happens, `add al, 200` or something, then `jc` (unsigned carry-out) or `jo` (signed overflow).  (See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).  `add al, 300` will truncate `300` to `49` at assemble-time, because the immediate can't be wider than the operand-size.

Comment: @PeterCordes, 300 would truncate to 44.  It is 305 that truncates to 49 ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback folks! I added an addendum to the question as the 32-bit overflow check seems to be a different case than the 8-bit and 16-bit. Does anyone have thoughts on why I'm seeing that behavior?

Comment: `2^32 - 1` is the max unsigned 32-bit value, not 2^32.  It has the same bit-pattern as signed 2's complement `-1`.  GCC is interpreting registers as signed integers by default because you didn't tell it otherwise.  `p (unsigned)$eax` if you want to tell it what to do with the bits.  There are many existing Q&As about how computers don't know whether a value in a register is signed or unsigned, it's up to the program to run instructions on them that treat them the way you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow `p (unsigned)$eax`. I had read that a computer doesn't think about signed or unsigned but I would have thought that a `mov eax, [int_32]` where the `int_32` label points to a value less than the max unsigned 32-bit value would just add zeros into the register to fill the upper 32-bits. And I didn't see anything in the documentation about `mov` or `push` being signed or unsigned by default.